# How can i add tags to Virtual Box VMs to orginze them?

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to add tags to VMs from Virtual Box to have a better orginzation.
I think about somethink like a projectnumber or a clientname or a emailadress of the owner.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

### VirtualBox tags?

You can organize your virtual machines in "folders" and rename the folders as you want, these are called (Virtual Machine Groups) and in my experience is the best way to organize things in VB, that's actually why they implemented that.

**How to**: you can just right-click the machine you want and select *group*, rename it and done.

**How to add more machines?** Just simply drag them into the group that you want.

Although you can do the above mentioned, you can also write some comments in the descriptions of the machines (which i find messy if i want to know what each machine is for, but good for keeping tips that could help me while working with them).